# Telling whether an Excel file was created/accessed with cracked version of the software

Tags: microsoft-excel, license

Is it possible to tell whether an Excel file has been created or accessed with pirated Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so. None of the file properties or metadata relates to whether the software used to create the file was/is legitimate.

Comment: Product license keys of the creator/users of the file don't get stored in the file?

Comment: No. If they were, I could take a file from you and use your product key to license my local install. Whose to say you bought it, or I bought it?